# sms autofill plugin error while working on chrome : Flutter

Tags: flutter, plugins, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

here is the error I'm getting while it's working fine on android and iOS.

```
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:54260/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:54260/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1560:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:54260/dart_sdk.js:40571:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:54260/dart_sdk.js:40441:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:54260/dart_sdk.js:35363:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:54260/dart_sdk.js:35931:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:54260/dart_sdk.js:35969:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:54260/dart_sdk.js:35817:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:54260/dart_sdk.js:35838:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:54260/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:54260/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
    at http://localhost:54260/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
```

Answer (score 1):

This package ([sms_autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill)) only covers Android and iOS and has no solution for Web-Flutter.

Comment: but I'm building app for web also so you mean I should write condition for devices <android> <iOS> only

Comment: yes , Ignore web-mode  in your code (use kisweb).